# Base current in a fixed bias BJT

Tags: transistors, bjt, biasing

Why does the base current remain nearly constant, neglecting V(be) in a fixed circuit bias for a bipolar junction transistor with respect to temperature? If Rb changes with temperature, the base current should change, too, as Ib = Vcc/Rb.

[image]

Comment: The base current is temperature dependent - in the same maner as the collector current is.

Comment: I agree that the simple biasing makes the transistor a thermometer instead of an amplifier.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't change (much) because hFE is fairly stable with temperature (particularly if you consider it in relation to the initial range of hFE). From [here](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/661741.pdf) you can see that Ib changes less than 3:1 over the entire -55°C to 125°C temperature range. For a narrow temperature range around room temperature it might change +/-10%.

The circuit you show is typically frowned upon or sneered at because of the initial tolerance, but it's workable if the transistors you buy are 'binned' in hFE range and the operating temperature range is fairly narrow (eg. a transistor radio). For example, an inexpensive C1815Y has a range of 120 to 240 at 2mA and 6V Vce so you can easily design a workable amplifier with such a part.

[image]

A  you suggest, the value of Rb will, of course, affect the base current but resistors are usually much more stable than the hFE. A cheap resistor might change 1/50 or 1/100 as much as hFE over the same temperature range and the initial tolerance would be 5% or 1% compared to +/-50%.

If Vbe does not change significantly then Ib will, of course, remain constant so long as Vcc and Rb remain constant (Ohm's law). As mentioned above, resistors are relatively stable parts. Since the changes in Vbe with temperature are typically pretty small compared to Vcc (-2mV/°C typically) that's usually an *excellent* approximation.

Comment: I think OP might also be confusing "RB" with "Rb" - the fixed (external) base resistor vs. the base input impedance.

Comment: @JonathanS. I should add something about the resistors, tks.

Comment: While it is true that the ratio Ic/Ib does not change very much with temperature, both currents are pretty sensitive to temperature variations. I think, THIS was the question. And both currents (Ib and Ic) in the shown circuit are not stabilized against temperature changes (no DC negative feedback)